# Docker Sharing Drives cannot login

Tags: docker

While sharing drive to run Linux containers, Docker comes up with a login prompt. O365 Username is pre-filled `AzureAD\(username given in c:\users\<username>)`.

I tried giving the password I logged in (0365 account). Tried changing username to logged-in username. Nothing works and it immediately goes back to the same `AzureAD\<username>` and prompts again (3 times)

Comment: awww.. secretly downvoting.. shhh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had logged in using O365 account. This did not allow me to provide access eventhough it was an admin user. But I had another login which was initially used to setup the windows 10 machine. When I used this login, I was able to provide access.